# Question about being a new user

Tags: discussion

I saw some interesting comments on your site so I signed up for your site; then I tried leaving a comment; it said I needed 'reputation' points.  I looked these up and these look very confusing and way too burdensome and cumbersome. It seems like with this approach you are limiting different opinions.

Just my feedback.  No response needed.

Comment: Thanks for your interest in  the site. This is a question and answer site, so personal opinions are not the important thing here. Answers showing what group of Christians believe something, with references, are preferred. We hope you will consider posting again when you have a question which can be stated so as to be within site guidelines, or an answer you can back up with references.

Answer (score 5):

> It seems like with this approach you are limiting different opinions.

Yes. That's kind of the point.

This site is not a discussion forum and we are really trying to avoid as much opinion based material as possible. Instead we want to see extant teachings of various groups explained from those groups' respective understandings. That's what answers should consist of, not people's opinions (right or wrong).

The comment function is deliberately limited to people who have posted a few regular questions and answers and gotten a feel for how the site works. Otherwise everybody that comes by off the internet would want to drop comments and turn every post into a discussion.

Even with 1 rep you are allowed to post questions an answers. Those are the bread and butter of the site and we encourage you to start there if you want to participate. Once you learn what is expected of regular posts it will be more apparent how comments are supposed to work and by that time you will have enough rep to use them.

Answer (score 4):

Start with asking and answering questions. They are the centrepiece of this site. Comments are only for asking for clarification. Think of them as little sticky notes affixed to a real post (a question or an answer), usually to point out a way it could be improved. Once that improvement has been addressed, comments can be, and often are, deleted.

Comments are not really *content*: they serve more the functions of an editor or a curator. As such, they are restricted to people who are reasonably familiar with how the site functions, as demonstrated by their having posted a few well-received questions and/or answers.

See the [Tour](/tour) for more information.